# How can I decrease an `id` column on all rows in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

How can I decrease an `id` column on all rows in a MySQL table?

For example:

`SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email FROM users u`

results in:

```
u.id  |  u.name  |  u.email 
---------------------------
1     | a        |  a
2     | a        |  a
3     | a        |  a
7     | a        |  a
8     | a        |  a
9     | a        |  a
```

but I want it so that 7 becomes 4, 8 becomes 5 etc.:

```
u.id  |  u.name  |  u.email 
---------------------------
1     | a        |  a
2     | a        |  a
3     | a        |  a
4     | a        |  a
5     | a        |  a
6     | a        |  a
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: `update u set id=id-1`, but you should never be changing ids like that. ids should be immutable.

Comment: What is the definition of the `id` column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an update like this, if all the ids that are over 7 should be decreased:

```
update users set id=id-4 where id>3;
```

Comment: I never knew that you could do something like the `id-4`. Learn something new every day ;-) Thanks!